# MaterializeCSS + Meteor mobile grid not working?

Tags: meteor, materialize

[here is a webpage that I ask about](http://erpegie.meteor.com/)

I use Meteor (Coffeescript + Jade + Stylus) with MaterializeCSS as front-end framework. I use grid (I think) properly. You can reproduce the problem I am facing by going there and resizing the web browser to the the mobile size. The grid will nicely adapt.

But when you try to actually go there on a mobile device the collapsible button will show but the rest of the page will look exactly like on a desktop making the page unreadable.

Any tips? Is this Meteor's fault or Materialize's? Also if you take a look here:

[marky.meteor.com](http://marky.meteor.com/) <- it will work and behave as intended and that page ALSO uses MaterializeCSS.

Any ideas why that happens and where the problem might lie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your header:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

Comment: I can't believe it could be that simple. Meteor made me lazy, I honestly assumed Meteor adds it by itself. It resolved problems with scaling on Chromium based browsers. I'll deploy app again and check on a mobile device.

edit: yeah, totally fixed.